# How to unlock my phone from pattern lock

Tags: lock-screens, pattern-lock

I am using an Android-based phone, a Moto G. By mistake it was locked with a pattern. I need to remove this pattern lock. How can I unlock it without losing the data on my phone?

Comment: Your question is unclear - do you want to delete the pattern lock or just unlock the phone? Unlock it with your pattern and you won't lose any data. Delete the pattern in lock settings and you won't lose any data either.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Google account you can reset the password and you will not lose the data. For more details please check FAQ on Motorola site https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/97840/p/30,6720,9102